# How to upload a video in chunks with JavaScript and save the video in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, upload, arraybuffer

Eventually I'd like to make adjustments to the users video from the client but for now I'm just trying to see how I can break a video up and send the data in chunks to my express server and save the file. Currently I can get a video file saved on my server but I think the data is corrupt as it won't actually play.

Here is my JavaScript for the Web Client:

```
const sendDataToBackend = (base64EncodedData) => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        data: base64EncodedData
    });
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body
    }).then(res => {
        return res.json()
    }).then(json => console.log(json));
}

function arrBuffToBase64( buffer ) {
    let binary = '';
    const bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    const len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}

const sendArrBuffToBackend = arrayBuffer => {
    console.debug('sendArrBuffToBackend', arrayBuffer)
    return sendDataToBackend(arrBuffToBase64(arrayBuffer));
}

const readBlob = (file, startByte, endByte) => {
    const start = startByte || 0;
    const end = endByte || file.size;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const blob = file.slice(start, end);
    console.debug('readBlob', start, end)

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        reader.onloadend = function (event) {
            if (event.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
                // Data has been read, invoke the complete method!
                res(event.target.result);
            }
        };

        reader.onerror = function (event) {
            rej(event.target.error.code);
        }
    })
};

const clone = async (file, start, end, onData) => {
    console.debug('cloning', { start, end });

    let currStart = start;
    let currEnd = start + CHUNK_SIZE;
    do {
        await onData(await readBlob(file, currStart, Math.min(currEnd, end)))
        currStart = currEnd + 1;
        currEnd = currStart + CHUNK_SIZE;
    } while (currEnd < end)
}

// this function is added to file input onchange
window.process = async function(fileInput) {
    const file = fileInput.files[0]
    await clone(file, 0, file.size, sendArrBuffToBackend)
}
```

Express Code:

```
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50MB", type:'application/json'}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {data} = req.body;
        const dataBuffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
        const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('faststart.mp4', {flags: 'a'});
        fileStream.write(dataBuffer);
        console.log(dataBuffer);
        return res.json({gotIt: true});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.json({gotIt: false});
    }
})
```